# Cross browser jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, cross-browser

I have a few jquery and ajax functions which work in google chrome perfectly.  When I use them in firefox though on my live server it does not work. Is this a known issue in firefox or is there a simple solution I have missed? I think that it mainly is having an issue with the AJAX code but I am not sure.

Here is my jquery code....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[id ^= 'toggle']").live("click", function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("div [id='replypost_"+$(this).attr('id').replace('toggle_','')+"']").toggle();
    });
});
```

Note: It also does not work in internet explorer. It only works in google chrome!

Comment: Be careful with spaces in selectors, that might be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of jquery are you using?

no `event` defined?

Try this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[id^='toggle']").live("click", function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           $("div [id='replypost_"+$(this).attr('id').replace('toggle_','')+"']").toggle();
       });
 });
```

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").on("click", "a[id^='toggle']", function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           $("div [id='replypost_"+$(this).attr('id').replace('toggle_','')+"']").toggle();
       });
 });
```

Comment: I bet the problem is that `event` wasn't defined as a parameter. The way you're using `.on()` **isn't** the `.live()` equivalent.

Comment: I am using .live() to handle now and future objects.

Comment: @KeithDrakeWaggoner You'll have to use something like `$(document).on("click", "a[id^='toggle']", function (event) { });`

Comment: @Keith [live() is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Its docs advise to use on() instead, and that older versions should use delegate() instead.

Comment: Got It That worked thank you so much I need to define the event

Comment: `$('a').on()` the selector must be a parent that is static. Like `body`.